# Error When Trying to Reset Password using macOS Recovery Mode

Tags: macos, terminal, passwords

I haven't used my old MacBook Pro for a while and forgot its password. So I tried resetpassword using Recovery Mode, but this error is displayed when I enter the password of my Apple ID:
"Couldn't sign in because of a server error. Try signing in again."

I have attached a screenshot containing terminal log as well.
[image: terminal log]

Sorry for the bad quality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after digging around for a long time, I came across a post (can't remember where) that simply stated "When you’re booting your Mac from the recovery partition, some errors might be caused by an incorrect system date setting".

So I went ahead and changed date using the terminal included in Recovery Utilities:

```
date -u {month}{day}{hour}{minute}{year}
```

Then, lo and behold, resetpassword is working flawlessly!